# GCP Dataproc - getting error in importing KafkaProducer

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I've a StructuredStreaming program running on GCP Dataproc,
when i import KafkaProducer, i get error shown below:

Imports :

```
import sys, datetime, time, os
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, rank, dense_rank, to_date, to_timestamp, format_number, row_number, lead, lag,monotonically_increasing_id
from google.cloud import storage
import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_timestamp,split as split_df, broadcast as s_broad, window
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, Window, Row
import calendar
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, StructField, StructType, BooleanType, ArrayType, IntegerType, LongType, DateType, TimestampType
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit, col, concat, regexp_replace, when, unix_timestamp, count as sql_count
import pandas as pd
import json
import copy
from google.cloud import bigquery
from kafka import KafkaProducer
```

The last import is causing error shown below :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/1b6daf68f83749b88536401dbcf7eb71/StructuredStreaming_GCP_Versa_Sase_gcloud.py", line 14, in <module>
    from kafka import KafkaProducer
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from kafka.producer import KafkaProducer
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .simple import SimpleProducer
  File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/simple.py", line 54
    return '<SimpleProducer batch=%s>' % self.async
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

While creation of the DataProc cluster, as part of 'initialization-actions',
i install the following:

```
pip install pypi
pip install kafka-python
pip install google-cloud-storage
pip install pandas
```

Any ideas what needs to be done to debug/fix this ?
tia!

Comment: You **do not need** that kafka Python package. It's not how you use Spark with Kafka. similarly, pandas functions should mostly all be done by Spark itself

Answer (score -1):

On Dataproc package kafka-python does not exist not installed as standard

`sudo su -` to root and install it as above

as root

pip list|grep kafka

```
root@ctpcluster-m:~# pip install kafka-python
Collecting kafka-python
  Downloading kafka_python-2.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (246 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 246 kB 22.0 MB/s
Installing collected packages: kafka-python
Successfully installed kafka-python-2.0.2
```

As a normal user

```
hduser@ctpcluster-m: /home/hduser> pip list|grep kafka
kafka-python                      2.0.2
```

Comment: While this answers the question, I don't think it's what OP really wants. This isn't needed for dataproc. Also, you shouldn't need to use sudo for pip

Comment: yes indeed this answers the question raised. I am answering a question not offering a solution on how to deploy Kafka with Spark or the validity of this approach.

Comment: Okay, and can you explain why sudo is needed? OP already claims they ran `pip install kafka-python` (which will not give the error in the post, by the way, since it's from `site-packages/kafka` import)

Comment: the OP opened a thread in https://lists.apache.org/list.html?user@spark.apache.org

I've a GCP Dataproc cluster, and I'm running a Spark StructuredStreaming job on this.
I'm trying to use KafkaProducer to push aggregated data into a Kafka topic,  however when i import KafkaProducer 
(from kafka import KafkaProducer), 
it gives error
.......
As part of the initialization actions, i'm installing the following :
---
pip install pypi
pip install kafka-python
pip install google-cloud-storage
pip install pandas

Hopefully you got i!

Comment: Hi All - the issue was due to incorrect pip_install.sh file i was using,  using the correct pip_install.sh (as initialization-action) resolved.. contents of pip_install.sh ```pip install pypi
pip install kafka-python
pip install google-cloud-storage
pip install pandas ```